# Capturing CMD.exe Triggers for Ephemeral Pop-ups

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I have a Windows 11.

At random point of time of the day, cmd.exe will pop up for a split second and then close again.

I have been trying to figure out how to capture what is triggering these creation of CMDs.

I have this specific script I found which collect what was ran recently , recent 25 record.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
>>     LogName = 'Security'
>>     ID = 4688
>> } | Select-Object TimeCreated,@{name='NewProcessName';expression={ $_.Properties[5].Value }}, @{name='CommandLine';expression={ $_.Properties[8].Value }} | select -First 25

TimeCreated          NewProcessName
-----------          --------------
22/7/2023 5:19:26 PM C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:19:26 PM C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
22/7/2023 5:19:25 PM C:\Windows\System32\consent.exe
22/7/2023 5:19:25 PM C:\Windows\System32\smartscreen.exe
22/7/2023 5:19:24 PM C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:19:24 PM C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:16:34 PM C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
22/7/2023 5:10:45 PM C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe
22/7/2023 5:10:44 PM C:\Windows\System32\consent.exe
22/7/2023 5:10:44 PM C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe
22/7/2023 5:10:44 PM C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:09:14 PM C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_10.2102.13.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad\N...
22/7/2023 5:08:54 PM C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:54 PM C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:54 PM C:\Windows\System32\smartscreen.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:54 PM C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:49 PM C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:48 PM C:\Windows\System32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
22/7/2023 5:08:45 PM C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WmiPrvSE.exe
22/7/2023 5:07:01 PM C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
22/7/2023 5:06:22 PM C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe
22/7/2023 5:06:22 PM C:\Windows\System32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
22/7/2023 5:02:20 PM C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SearchProtocolHost.exe
22/7/2023 5:00:38 PM C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22000.2173_none_...
```

But this does not point to who's the "actor" or "trigger actor".
I have Custom XML event viewer created to monitor CMD.exe but I feel like it is not accurate too :

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security"> *[System[(EventID=4688)] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Result -
[image: Event Viewer]

I am running out of ideas. I have been working on this for the past 3 days and I could not find a definite solution on finding what is triggering cmd.exe to pop up.

I do not see the possibility of including the /k parameter as default for any cmd trigger.
What can I do here?
My objective is to either keep the cmd that was called to stay open so I can pinpoint the culprit , or , have a monitoring tool to audit cmd.exe creation.

Additional point :

1. I have enabled Audit on cmd.exe in Group Policy.
2. It is my own personal device.

UPDATE 1 :
It is still happening after all changes made from this thread.
[image]
The highlighted part is what was called seconds after my screen was all minimized and a "command prompt" like screen was shown for a split second.

Comment: How do you know it is cmd.exe specifically?

Comment: @u1686_grawity , Well , I can see the Command Prompt opening for less than a second.

Comment: Is it titled "Command Prompt" specifically, or is it just a window that looks like a Command Prompt window in general?

Comment: @u1686_grawity , i would think it is command prompt specifically.
It could also be conhost.exe , as I can see both of them triggered in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[4688(S): A new process has been created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4688), it does **not require elevated permission** or **[UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works) consent to execute** since it's using `type 3` and assuming you have UAC enabled.

> `%%1938`: Type `3` is a limited token with administrative privileges removed and administrative groups disabled. The limited token is used *when User Account Control is enabled*, the application ***does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator***.
>
> <sub>[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4688)</sub>

To help narrow down the executing process and assess the possibility of **modifying it to utilize the `cmd /k` parameter** or **suppress the terminal window pop-up**.

- Review Event Viewer security logs (and other relevant logs) by filtering them **starting before** the timestamp when Event ID `4688` processes initiate.
- Run [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to determine if it can capture more verbose detail.
- Inspect [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler) jobs, including all subcontainers, to search for the item or related parameters within each job's fields in the tabbed views—it's possible to search this quicker using PowerShell.
- Lastly, you should run the **correlated executables** through [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to confirm **with a high level of confidence** that the *executables are not malicious* (drag and drop).

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin ... This response offers additional pointers to aid in narrowing down the trigger and potentially finding a solution to suppress the pop-up window. It also provides a resource to verify the executable's legitimacy with a high level of confidence, addressing the core question within its scope as per my interpretation.

Comment: Hey! One of the pointer gave me an idea. You mentioned about UAC.

My current config is - "Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer ( default ) "
with sub-config - "Dont' Notify me when I make changes to Windows Settings.

I have modified this to - Always Notify.

This is the only step that I have not tried or perform.

I have reviewed 30 minutes range of Event Viewer a few seconds after CMD can be seen on the screen.  - Part 1

Comment: I reached maximum comment characters. 
Let me go through the night and see if cmd triggers again and if any UAC triggers. With this, it should tell me WHICH app is calling CMD.

Comment: The Event Viewer logs, such as **Application and Services, and Windows PowerShell logs, and others within** can provide valuable details. Investigating with Process Explorer around the same time frame starting "before" `4688` occurs might reveal another process responsible for the execution triggering, operating with its own logic or scheduling mechanism which is not easily identifiable. While the log shows the executor and what it executes, the triggering factor remains unclear. If adjusting UAC settings doesn't help, examining service.exe in Process Explorer or other logs could be useful.

Comment: Hey, it seems to still be happening though. Im really curious now.. 
Updated in to the post..

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it seems that the culprits could be the `GamePassWidget.AppX~` and `Microsoft.Xbox.App.AppX` UWP apps. If you don't use Xbox via UWP or at all on this system, consider removing these apps and their correlated GamePassWidget appx packages to see if it resolves the issue. Also, check for any group policy settings, as routine `gpupdate` might be running on a domain joined machine, causing other processes to check for updates at login. Does the issue occur specifically at login when you notice? Also is this machine domain joined?

Comment: Hey. No , the PC is not under any domain and it does not happen on login.
It will happen at very random times. I am at the point where I will perform a clean install instead

Answer (score 4):

Your image has the answer :

```
Creator Process Name: C:\Program Files\Google\Play Games\current\service\Service.exe
Process Command Line: "cmd" /c vulkaninfo.exe
```

The Vulkaninfo process is related to the Vulkan graphics API used
by modern graphics cards like AMD and NVIDIA.
This file is in my System32 too and it's signed by Intel,
so it's totally legit.

I suggest updating your graphic driver to the latest version from
the manufacturer's website. Check also if you can update
Google Play Games or limit its actions.

Comment: As a programmer who has replaced `malloc`in the past to track allocations: Could one replace the original `cmd.exe` (for example `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`) by a self-written program which obtains information and then calls the original `cmd.exe` (which has been renamed to something else, say `cmd-original.exe`) with the original command line parameters?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: That's an enormous project you're looking at. See FreeDOS to get an appreciation.

Comment: Hm. I'm not looking to remove and re-implement `cmd.exe` but rather to install a man in the middle.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: This is possible, but will require replacing CMD from System32 and renaming the original. It's is not recommended to change System32 software from Microsoft, and there might be some difficulties with its ownership by the privileged TrustedInstaller account.